# pandas date column subtraction

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this..

```
       created_time  reached_time
2016-01-02 12:57:44      14:20:22
2016-01-02 12:57:44      13:01:38
2016-01-03 10:38:51      12:24:07
2016-01-03 10:38:51      12:32:11
2016-01-03 10:38:52      12:23:20
2016-01-03 10:38:52      12:51:34
2016-01-03 10:38:52      12:53:33
2016-01-03 10:38:52      13:04:08
2016-01-03 10:38:52      13:13:40
```

I want to subtract these two date columns and want to get `time`

I am doing following in python

```
speed['created_time'].dt.time - speed['reached_time']
```

But it gives me following error

`TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('O') and dtype('<m8[ns]')`

datatype of `created_time` is `object` and datatype of `reached_type` is `timedelta64[ns]`

Comment: Please post `speed.info()`. If you can use `speed['created_time'].dt`, then I think the dtype of `speed['created_time']` must be `datetime64[ns]`, not `'O'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could drop down to NumPy arrays and do the [datetime/timedelta arithmetic](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-and-timedelta-arithmetic) there. First, create an array of dates of dtype `datetime64[D]`:

```
dates = speed['created_time'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
```

Then you have two options: you could convert `reached_time` to dates, and subtract dates from dates:

```
speed['reached_date'] = dates + speed['reached_time'].values
speed['diff'] = speed['created_time'] - speed['reached_date']
```

or you could convert `created_time` to timedeltas, and subtract timedeltas from timedeltas:

```
speed['created_delta'] = speed['created_time'].values - dates
speed['diff'] = speed['created_delta'] - speed['reached_time']
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

speed = pd.DataFrame(
    {'created_time': 
     ['2016-01-02 12:57:44', '2016-01-02 12:57:44', '2016-01-03 10:38:51',
      '2016-01-03 10:38:51', '2016-01-03 10:38:52', '2016-01-03 10:38:52',
      '2016-01-03 10:38:52', '2016-01-03 10:38:52', '2016-01-03 10:38:52'],
     'reached_time': 
     ['14:20:22', '13:01:38', '12:24:07', '12:32:11', '12:23:20', 
      '12:51:34', '12:53:33', '13:04:08', '13:13:40']})
speed['reached_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(speed['reached_time'])
speed['created_time'] = pd.to_datetime(speed['created_time'])

dates = speed['created_time'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')

speed['reached_date'] = dates + speed['reached_time'].values
speed['diff'] = speed['created_time'] - speed['reached_date']

# alternatively
# speed['created_delta'] = speed['created_time'].values - dates
# speed['diff'] = speed['created_delta'] - speed['reached_time']

print(speed)
```

yields

```
         created_time  reached_time        reached_date              diff
0 2016-01-02 12:57:44      14:20:22 2016-01-02 14:20:22 -1 days +22:37:22
1 2016-01-02 12:57:44      13:01:38 2016-01-02 13:01:38 -1 days +23:56:06
2 2016-01-03 10:38:51      12:24:07 2016-01-03 12:24:07 -1 days +22:14:44
3 2016-01-03 10:38:51      12:32:11 2016-01-03 12:32:11 -1 days +22:06:40
4 2016-01-03 10:38:52      12:23:20 2016-01-03 12:23:20 -1 days +22:15:32
5 2016-01-03 10:38:52      12:51:34 2016-01-03 12:51:34 -1 days +21:47:18
6 2016-01-03 10:38:52      12:53:33 2016-01-03 12:53:33 -1 days +21:45:19
7 2016-01-03 10:38:52      13:04:08 2016-01-03 13:04:08 -1 days +21:34:44
8 2016-01-03 10:38:52      13:13:40 2016-01-03 13:13:40 -1 days +21:25:12
```

---

Using [HRYR's improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536053/pandas-date-column-subtraction/35536681#comment58761998_35536435), you can do the computation without dropping down to NumPy arrays (i.e. no need to access `.values`):

```
dates = speed['created_time'].dt.normalize()
speed['reached_date'] = dates + speed['reached_time']
speed['diff'] = speed['created_time'] - speed['reached_date']
```

Comment: The `create_time` is before the `reached_date`. Subtracting a later datetime from an earlier datetime produces a negative timedelta. If you want a positive timedelta, use `speed['reached_date'] - speed['created_time']`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `created_time` column to datetime first:

```
df["created_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["created_time"])
```

Then use `df["created_time"] - df["created_time"].dt.normalize()` to get the time part as `timedelta` type.

Comment: I did that but still gives me an error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'`

Comment: use `df["created_time"] - df["created_time"].dt.normalize()` to get the time part.