# Subtracting between different datetype values in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
raw_data = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15'],'SeriesDate':['2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-14','2017-03-15']}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns=['Series_Date','SeriesDate'])
print df
```

However, on running the following comands:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
df['SeriesDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SeriesDate'])
df['Start_Date'] = df['SeriesDate'] - BDay(10)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')
```

How can I work around this?

Comment: df['SeriesDate'] = pd.to_datetime(series['SeriesDate'])
    df['StartDate'] = df['SeriesDate'] - timedelta(days=10)
    df['EndDate'] = df['SeriesDate'] - timedelta(days=3)
    print df

When I try to do this:

    df['DateDifference'] = ((df.StartDate- df.EndDate) / 2).dt.ceil('D')

I get the following error:

    TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')

Any idea how I can overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Code works fine for me. So I'm guessing there's some problems in your environment. You can read up a similar answer here: [pandas date column subtraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536053/pandas-date-column-subtraction)

Would have commented instead of an answer, but I do not have enough rep to do so.