# Subtracting a Pandas Date from another Date Giving lots of Errors

Tags: python, pandas

I am scanning a list of dates to find the minimum date in a Pandas Dataframe, then subtracting the minimum date from all others to get the number of days between the minimum date and the others. It was working on my computer with the below code:

```
MinDay = a1_raw_data['EventDate'].min()
a1_raw_data['DaysSince'] = (a1_raw_data['EventDate'] - MinDay) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

I am now trying it on a cloud and it seems to be giving me and error by interpreting it as a string:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

In addition I have tried tried converting both to dates like below:

```
MinDay = a1_raw_data['EventDate'].min()

MinDay = pd.to_datetime(MinDay)
a1_raw_data['EventDate'] = pd.to_datetime(a1_raw_data['EventDate'])

a1_raw_data['DaysSince'] = (a1_raw_data['EventDate'] - MinDay) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

Error:

```
TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood
```

and have modified the subtraction, like below:

```
MinDay = a1_raw_data['EventDate'].min()

MinDay = pd.to_datetime(MinDay)
a1_raw_data['EventDate'] = pd.to_datetime(a1_raw_data['EventDate'])

a1_raw_data['DaysSince'] = (a1_raw_data['EventDate'].subtract(MinDay)) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

Error:

```
TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')
```

Any ideas on how to subtract would be appreciated?

Thanks

Update

Thanks to the example Pygirl gave me I seem to have gotten it working as below:

```
MinDay = a1_raw_data['EventDate'].min()

MinDay = pd.to_datetime(MinDay)
MinDay = np.array(MinDay,dtype=np.datetime64)

EventDate = pd.to_datetime(a1_raw_data['EventDate'])
EventDate = np.array(EventDate,dtype=np.datetime64)

a1_raw_data['DaysSince'] = EventDate - MinDay
```

So thanks. But now it is very slow due to having to convert a1_raw_data['EventDate'] into np.arrays(). Is there a more efficient way someone could suggest? As when I was doing it on my desktop the below line was working

```
MinDay = a1_raw_data['EventDate'].min()
a1_raw_data['DaysSince'] = (a1_raw_data['EventDate'] - MinDay) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

Now it needs all the above on a different computer. I tried it with just converting MinDay to an np.array() as the example did, but that didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: What do you get with 'MinDay.dtypes' and 'a1_raw_data.EventDate.dtypes' after applying 'pd.to_datetime' ?

Comment: This one is similar to your query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536053/pandas-date-column-subtraction 
Check this out.

Comment: Thanks Pygirl. I got it working using the solution you linked to but its now very slow, as you can see from my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your comment jlesueur. for type(MinDay) I get 'str' and for a1_raw_data['RaceDate'].dtypes I get dtype('O')